# is there an easy way to find the inflection point of this function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

From a past exam. For the function y=x(x-3)^2/5, is there trick to find the inflection point? Doing the second derivative takes a while and gives messy results, and the space they give me to work out the problem is small and can't fit everything in there comfortably, which makes me think that there's a shorter way, but if there is its over my head right now.

Comment: Well, $y$ can be written as a polynomial with highest power $3$ if you just multiply everything out. Then taking the derivative is a fairly trivial matter.

Comment: Easiest to first expand, then take the second derivative.

Comment: User, maybe it's my lack of math understanding showing, but how would I expand a factor with a power of 2/5?

Comment: It is not clear that the "/5" was part of the exponent. It is also not clear whether the exponent 2/5 applies to the x-3 only or to x(x-3). You can format $P^{2/5}$  as P^{2/5}.

Answer (score 1):

The first derivative is 
$$y'=\dfrac15\bigl((x-3)^2+2x(x-3)\bigr)=\frac35(x-3)(x-1) $$
Now the inflection point correspond to the minimum of this quadratic polynomial, and the extremum of a quadratic polynomial is attained at the midsum of  its roots, i.e. at $\color{red}{2}$ in the present case.